# Error While Deploying a Django App on Railway.app

Tags: django, railway

self.load_wsgi()

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi

self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi

self.callable = self.load()

^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load

return self.load_wsgiapp()

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp

return util.import_app(self.app_uri)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app

mod = importlib.import_module(module)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/root/.nix-profile/lib/python3.11/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in import_module

return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "", line 1204, in _gcd_import

File "", line 1176, in _find_and_load

File "", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dostanaapp.wsgi'

[2023-11-17 02:46:30 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)

[2023-11-17 02:46:30 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:9) exited with code 3

[2023-11-17 02:46:30 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Shutting down: Master

[2023-11-17 02:46:30 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

[2023-11-17 02:47:22 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0

[2023-11-17 02:47:22 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:6275 (1)

[2023-11-17 02:47:22 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync

[2023-11-17 02:47:22 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9

[2023-11-17 02:47:22 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker

worker.init_process()

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process

self.load_wsgi()

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi

self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi

self.callable = self.load()

^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load

return self.load_wsgiapp()

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp

return util.import_app(self.app_uri)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app

mod = importlib.import_module(module)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/root/.nix-profile/lib/python3.11/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in import_module

return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "", line 1204, in _gcd_import

File "", line 1176, in _find_and_load

File "", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dostanaapp.wsgi'

[2023-11-17 02:47:22 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)

[2023-11-17 02:47:22 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:9) exited with code 3

[2023-11-17 02:47:22 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Shutting down: Master

[2023-11-17 02:47:22 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

Answer (score 0):

Alright Guys So I fixed it myself, and here is solution:
[As shown in screenshot click on +Start command and add command python3 manage.py runserver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDtsI.png)

After that let it redeploy and watch out for logs, it will show you any missing
package name, in my case `pillow` was missing. Add any missing packages in `requirements.txt` and after that check logs if there are no errors.
Remove Start Command leave it empty and it will automatically start the `Gunicorn` server correctly.